# Proving a group where every element's square is identity is Abelian

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

$G$ is a group with the property that the square of every element is the identity, then $G$ is abelian. Is my proof correct?

Attempt:

For every $a \in G, \space a^2 = e$ where $e$ is the identity element of $G$.

$a^2 = e \implies a = a^{-1}$**

$G$ is abelian if $\forall a,b \in G, \space ab=ba$

So we proceed:

if $ab = ba$

$ab\times a^{-1}b^{-1}=e$

By **

$\implies ab\times ab = e$
$\implies (ab)^2 = e$

By hypothesis this is true.

~ My question is; is this correct and also why does the $a$ from the right side get moved over first? Would I be able to write

if $ab = ba$

$ab\times a^{-1}b^{-1}=e$

as

if $ab = ba$

$ab\times b^{-1}a^{-1}=e$

with the $b$ first or does the order of moving elements over matter?

Comment: If "$G$ is abelian" is what you want to prove, why do you beg the question and say "if $ab=ba$?

Comment: No.... that isn't correct.  You are attempting to prove that if the particular $a$ and $b$ that you chose commute it is compatible with this group property.  You need to show that this group property forces that *any* $a$ and $b$ will commute.

Answer (score 1):

Note that every element is its own inverse.

Therefore,

$$ (ab)=(ab)^{-1} = b^{-1}a^{-1} =ba$$

That is the group is Abelian.

Comment: Why does $(ab)^{-1} = b^{-1}a^{-1}$ Why do you reverse the order of a and b

Comment: $abb^{-1}a^{-1}=e$

Comment: It's a well known identity of *any* group that $(ab)^{-1} = b^{-1}a^{-1}$.  This is because $(ab)(b^{-1}a^{-1}) =a(bb^{-1})a^{-1}=aa^{-1} =e$.  This is true for *all* groups.

Answer (score 0):

We know $(ab)(ab) = abab =e$. Consider the product $w=ababba$.  On the one hand, $w=(abab)(ba) = e(ba)=ba$.  On the other, $w=ababba = aba(bb)a=abaea=abaa = ab(e)=ab$.

Comment: This is true in every group.  $abb^{-1}a^{-1}=e$

Comment: It's true of every group that $abb^{-1}a^{-1} = e$ but it not true of every group that $abba = abb^{-1}a^{-1}=(ab)(ab)^{-1}  =abab$.

Comment: in this group we know that every element is its own inverse,

Answer (score 0):

Simple non-general case.

$e = (ab)(ab) = bb =aa$.

So

$ab = a*e*b = a*[(ab)(ab)]*b=$

$(a*a)(ba)(b*b) = e*(ba)*e = ba$.

Ta-da!

....

More general but probably more usefull is

For any $k \in G$ then $k^2 = k*k =e$.  So *by definition* $k^{-1} = k$ for every $k$.

So $(ab)^{-1} = ab$.

Now it's a *basic* identity of *every* group that

$(ab)*(b^{-1} a^{-1}) = a*(b*b^{-1})*a^{-1}= a*e*a^{-1} = a*a^{-1} =e$.

So $(ab)^{-1} = b^{-1} a^{-1}$.

So in *this* group we have:

$ab = (ab)^{-1} = b^{-1} a^{-1} = ba$.